# What does »L« mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviation, dictionary

As I was looking up the verb *aufkreuzen* in *[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/aufkreuzen)*, I came across the following example of the verb's usage:

> der Dieb kreuzte **in L** auf und wurde festgenommen

What does *L* mean? If *X* had been used in the sentence instead of *L*, it could have probably meant any location, just for the sake of this example. But I don't remember ever seeing *L* as a replacement for *X* in such a situation.

Answer (score 4):

It's an abbreviation. In juristical texts, names of people and locations are shortened to the first letter after they first appeared and police jargon follows this.

It could also be an abbreviation following the German car license plate system. L is Leipzig area then.

Comment: Ich halte es eher für eine Form der Anonymisierung (Herr K. aus L. ) als den Gebrauch eines bestimmten, eingeführten Begriffs. Die Annahme, man folge den Autokennzeichen, halte ich für weit hergeholt.

Comment: @userunknown: Using license plate abbreviations is quite common, in my circles at least. You can even see them on street signs occasionally, e.g. when denoting areas of a city like "M-Pasing" for München-Pasing .

Comment: @Gerhard: Du müsstest schon mit etwas beeindruckenderem daherkommen als M.-Pasing, etwa HL- oder MTK-irgendwas. Das würde aber dann immer noch nicht bedeuten, dass es in juristisch/polizeiliche und journalistische Sprachgepflogen eingewandert ist.

Comment: @userunknown: there is, however, absolutely no context given. I would not have placed a sentence like this into a judicial- or police-text (and I have little idea of what is customary here in terms of abbreviations), as "aufkreuzen" is rather informal. To me, this is something somebody could say/email/text/blog, with some stretch of imagination it might appear in a (local?) newspaper. But again - who knows, there is no context. I am just saying that licence plates are sometimes used as abbreviations.

Comment: @userunknown: as for other examples: in my experience, the use on street signs is (naturally) more limited to cities, like HD-xxx. For "Kreise" this use does not make sense, but especially for the more unwieldy ones ("MTK") their use in texts is not unheard of (e.g. http://www.kreisblatt.de/lokales/main-taunus-kreis/Hier-waren-Polizei-und-Feuerwehr-im-MTK-an-Silvester-im-Einsatz;art676,2402749). Googleing "im MTK" (with quotation marks) yields more results.

Comment: Note that quite a number of E.A. Poe and H.P. Lovecraft stories tend to use 1-letter abbreviations for places as well - As an *anonymous proof of authenticity*

Comment: http://autobahnatlas-online.de/Bildergalerie/A39_bs_276.jpg

Comment: @Janka: Anekdotische Evidenz. Wenn man seit Stunden auf Braunschweig zufährt, dann bekommt man zweifellos mit, dass man jetzt in Braunschweig ist, zumindest wenn man am Rande damit rechnet jetzt da zu sein und sich für die Unterschiede von BS-Süd und BS-Südstadt interessiert. In dem einen Satz des Beispiels dagegen ist gar kein Kontext gegeben und L könnte auch Luzern oder Linz heißen, da der einzig bekannte Kontext dt. Sprache ist, nicht wahr, selbst wenn es um Autokennzeichen geht (ohne die Gepflogenheiten der Schweiz und Österreichs zu kennen)?

Comment: Deshalb schrieb ich ja auch "könnte ebenso". Diese Nomenklatur findest du jedenfalls **überall** auf Wegweisern, ebenso auf Ortsausgangsschildern, sofern notwendig.

Answer (score 3):

In this example, *X* could have been used as well as *L*. *L* has no special meaning. Perhaps not so many locations, towns or villages start with the letter *X*, so *L* might sound more colourful in the context of this sentence.

(I personally regard this "location anomyzation" as unnecessary and the example could as well say "der Dieb kreuzte in Leipzig auf und wurde festgenommen" without offending anybody.)

Comment: It could be not anonymization, but perhaps just an abbreviation, referring to the location established earlier in a report. Taken out of context won't tell us anything, of course.